How can i calculate dangling bond density of Si plane?
I've researched how to calculate number of dangling bonds in Si plane (100) , (110), (111)...
I can't figure out how to approach.
Is there any way to do so?
I searched one report that in FCC structure if i slice along the (100) plane , then 4 nearest atoms disappear and each atom has 4 nearest and I don't understand because the center atom of (100) plane has nearest 12 atoms..

At the least, remember that silicon is diamond cubic, not pure fcc. But it takes some familiarity with the crystal structure and a 3D model is helpful.

It is probably thye easiest to use a 3-D depiction of a fcc Si unit cell showing the Si atoms together with their tetrahedal covalent bonds. You can find such a picture, e.g., in the book by Simon Sze, "Physics of Semiconductor Devices. Then you could count the "dangling bonds" for different plane cuts.
This, however, gives you the dangling bonds for plane cuts through the undisturbed crystal. At the surface of a real Si crystal, a so-called surface reconstruction takes place which changes the bonds and atomic positions at the crystal surface.
